# Помогите, пожалуйста, определить род существительных

Tags: морфология, существительные

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить род существительных: МИЛОНГА и ТАНДА. Спасибо! Столкнулась с этой проблемой. Буду очень благодарна.

Answer (score 2):

У слова ТАНДА есть несколько значений. Вы, скорее всего, имеете в виду термин из мира танцев. Оба существительных - женского рода, судя по формам согласуемых с этими словами прилагательных в источниках. Источники: [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0), [Словарь](http://urokitango.kiev.ua/index.php/ru/pro-tango/83-ctati-o-tango/89-slovar-tango-terminov) танго-терминов, [Школа](http://www.tangocity.ru/tango/muzyka-tango/dj/tanda) аргентинского танго

Comment: Вы по **склонению** можете определить грамматический род существительного на -А?  Научите? **Воевода**, допустим, vs** вода**.  Ну про "аргументированную" ссылку на интернет, я уже не говорю.

Comment: см. ответ, который дала @Sibylla

Comment: _М_Г: "судя по тому, как их склоняют в источниках"_. === Лучше, по-моему, написать так: _"судя по формам согласуемых с этими словами прилагательных"._

Comment: @slava1947 Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @ М_Г  *см. ответ, который дала* - А что я там должен смотреть?

Comment: @Morkovkin,  представьте, что Вы никогда не слышали слова "антраша",  не знаете,  что оно означает и куда ставить ударение, одушевленное оно или неодушевленное, в словаре слова еще нет.  Именно так был поставлен вопрос. Можете определить его род без Интернета,  без знания предмета (использовать можно только  "общую  закономерность языка").

Answer (score 2):

Женского. С очень большой, почти абсолютной, долей уверенности.

Я не знаю других значений, но это даже не принципиально.
То, как "склоняют" (М_Г) в Интернете, тоже не всегда доказательно. Доказательным, строго говоря, является только словарь, а доступными словарями термины пока не фиксируются.

Но тут выручает общая закономерность языка. Грамматически неодущевленных нарицательных имен мужского рода с окончаниям на -А/-Я **не бывает** (кроме единичных форм типа "домина" и "дымина"). Остается - женский род.

Видимо, носители языка это хорошо чувствуют, поэтому и предпочитают согласование по женскому роду. Признаться, не ожидал, что у кого-то этот факт может вызвать затруднение.

*Я абсолютный профан в танцах и их терминологии, но тут все ясно и без знания предмета*

Добавлю. - 26.02.2018
Меня убедили, что, с позиций буквоедства нельзя исключать вариант со средним родом, но это никак не сказывается на логике описанного. У меня было "с почти абсолютной уверенностью". Вот это-то "почти" мне вроде как в вину и поставили. Не буду спорить, ну кто-то всерьез рассматривает возможность среднего рода, все равно это рассуждения не являются строго доказательными, доказательно - только словарь.

Comment: К счастью, без знания предмета Вам удались угадать, что речь идет о неодушевленном нарицательном. А ведь есть и мужское имя Танда, и географические названия Танда, род которых не вполне очевиден.

Comment: _Morkovkin: Грамматически неодущевленных нарицательных имен мужского рода с окончаниям на -А/-Я не бывает (кроме единичных форм типа "домина" и "дымина"). Остается - женский род._ === А почему остаётся **только** женский род? Ведь кроме мужского и женского есть ещё и средний...

Comment: @slava1947 -  *Ведь кроме мужского и женского есть ещё и средний* Вы серьезно? - назовите хоть одно нормальное нарицательное существительное среднего рода подобного типа. Я даже с собственным не могу придумать. Ну хорошо, "баккара" - какое-то недоразумение в словарях, я и значения такого толком не знаю. Но еще-то?

Answer (score 2):

**Танда, милонга**... Можно ли однозначно определить род незнакомых  слов по окончанию А, если вы не знаете их значения? Нет, нельзя, нужно знать, о каком предмете идет речь, — **одушевленном или неодушевленном.**

И вот тогда **приходится** обратиться к Интернету, если в словаре этого слова еще нет, а заодно и получить минимальные сведения   из области культуры (тоже не помешают).

**Из Интернета**

**Танда** — это сет из нескольких мелодий танго, милонги или вальса. В Буэнос-Айресе музыку на милонге ставят тандами, состоящими, как правило, из четырех мелодий.

**Милонга** — южноамериканский **танец,** а также **танцевальный вечер**, на котором танцуют танго, танго-вальс и милонгу. Также, в последнее время, на милонгах в Буэнос-Айресе и кое-где в Европе танцуют еще два танца: чакареру и кандомбе.

Собственного говоря, для определения рода мы должны быть уверены, что эти слова обозначают **неодушевленный предмет.** Тогда можно сказать, что они **женского рода**, так как **к мужскому (а также общему) роду** относятся только **одушевленные** сущ. на А: мужчина. юноша, вельможа, сластена, непоседа (кроме уже названных единичных слов с оценочным значением типа дымина/домина).

**Поэтому мы говорим**: субботняя/праздничная милонга (вечеринка); наконец-то наступает она — первая милонга (танец); не корректно оставлять партнера, пока танда (сет) не закончилась.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Разумеется, всё сказанное относится **к склоняемым существительным**, потому что для несклоняемых слов определение рода подчиняется особым правилам. Существительное однозначно не склоняется, если оно не вписываются в словоизменительную систему русского языка, в частности не склоняются слова с ударным окончанием А, например "амплуа". Большинство неодушевленных сущ. в этом случае относят к среднему роду.

2) **А вот "баккара" (род хрусталя) какого рода?** Берем словарь и видим, что ему ожидаемо приписывают **ср. род** (в то время как для карточной игры возможны два варианта: м.род и ж.род).

**БАККАРА**, неизм.; ср. [франц. baccarat]. Один из наиболее ценных сортов хрусталя. ●По названию г. Баккара во Франции, где с 1816 г. производился такой хрусталь. **БАККАРА**, неизм.; м. и ж. [франц. baccara]. Старинная азартная карточная игра, в которой несколько игроков играют против ведущего игру.

Но вот в художественных текстах средний род используется не всегда, например: Кольца, браслеты давно в ломбарде, **баккара побита**. [Ирина Муравьева. (1991)].  Только звякают на маленьком ветру стебли травы, превратившиеся в толстые хрустальные колосья. Такая **смертельная баккара**. [Татьяна Толстая.  2012]. Но: Пожалуйста, осторожней! Ты разобьешь **моё баккара**. [Анатолий Мариенгоф (1927)].

Что тут скажешь, кто прав? Такое впечатление, что правы все, и надо бы указать в словаре, что возможен ср. род или ж. род.

А вот ж. род для карточной игры (м.р. вроде бы не очень подходит): **Парижская баккара** имеет свою особенность ― это скорее банк ― баккара. [Н. Э. Гейнце. Герой конца века (1898)]

Comment: _Sibylla: Собственного говоря, для определения рода мы должны быть уверены, что эти слова обозначают неодушевленный предмет. Тогда можно сказать, что они **женского рода**_. === Ну а какого рода, к примеру, слово **баккара** (сорт хрусталя)? Тоже женского?

Comment: @slava1947 По-моему, все сказаное в этом ответе верно для изменяемых  сущ. Отдельный случай - иностранные слова, в которых ударение падает на последнее А. Они, как правило, неизменяемые, напр. баккара́ .

Comment: *Берем словарь и видим, что ему ожидаемо приписывают ср. род* - совершенно неожидаемо. Вообще логику ответа ожидаемо не понял. Правка - чтобы убрать минус.

Comment: Как определяется род несклоняемых существительных?  Нарицательные неодушевленные существительные чаще всего относятся к среднему роду. Особые правила действуют для одушевленных существительных, обозначающих лиц и животных, топонимов, а также при наличии   общего   родового понятия (например, знойный сирокко - ветер).